# Mongo does not want to delete

Tags: mongodb

I use remove and `deleteMany` and `deleteOne`, with curly brackets, and without but query always shows that they were not deleted, just always.

```
Author.deleteMany({}) Book.deleteMany({})
```

Even `deleteOne ({})` does not work!

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    minlength: 4
  },
  born: {
    type: Number,
  },
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Author', schema)

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    minlength: 2
  },
  published: {
    type: Number,
  },
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Author'
  },
  genres: [
    { type: String}
  ]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model ('Book', schema)
```

Comment: Please provide more code you your question, and format it correctly

Comment: Author.deleteMany({})
Book.deleteMany({})    do not work.
Book.deleteOne({title: 'Pimeyden tango'}) does not work.

Author.remove({})
Book.remove({}) do not work.

Comment: @3circles, please add it to the original question via edit button, not as a comment below. Also, it still poorly describes the problem. Please read this first, before asking https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I should have used .then or await. Only they get all documents deleted

Comment: It's because query isn't a promise, you could also add `.exec()` and they your query will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

const results = await this.Book.deleteMany({});